# Why Fitting subgroup is well defined?

Tags: group-theory

Fitting subgroup is the product of all nilpotent normal subgroup in the group G. Also it is equivalent to direct sum of all p radicals, where p divides group order. What does it meant by Fitting sub group is well defined and why?
Please help.

Comment: Well, for one: can you prove that a product of normal nilpotent subgroups is a nilpotent (normal) subgroup? In fact, the Fitting subgroup can be more accurately, perhaps, be characterized as the unique biggest normal nilpotent subgroup of a group.

Comment: Yes, we have a theorem for two nilpotent normal subgroups, that product will also, nilpotent normal. by induction it follows. then why well defined?

Comment: Becauser we want a *largest* nilpotent normal subgroup, and taking the product of **all** the nilpotent normal sbgps. we achieve this...Of course, one must know from long ago that the product of two groups, of which at least one is normal, is again a subgroup...Beyond this I can't figure out what else to say.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much. I am reading for the exam. Maybe that's what the examiner expected.